# Adding a picture box with a mouse click WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

At the moment I'm trying to create a black image box that appears when I press my left mouse button. However, when I click, nothing happens.

Could someone please have a look at what I'm doing wrong?

In my Image class:

```
 PictureBox _pictureBoxTag = new PictureBox();

    private List<PictureBox> _displayedImage = new List<PictureBox>();

    public void AddPictureBox()
    {
        try
        {
            PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
            _picBox.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            _picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            _picBox.BackColor = Color.Black;
            _picBox.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            _displayedImage.Add(_picBox);



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then in my Form1.cs class

```
   HV_Image _testImage;
_testImage = new HV_Image();
  private void MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                _testImage.AddPictureBox();
                Trace.WriteLine("Picture box added");
            }

            Trace.WriteLine("Mouse Click");
        }
```

My thinking was that my image class should contain a list of picture boxes that get filled out with the required information to create one. E.g size, colour, location etc. Then in my Form1.cs class I simply call the function and it'll draw.

If my way is terrible, or wont work, is there another way in which I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the x and y position of the image, else it will get added to the same spot each time.

```
public void AddPictureBox(int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
            _picBox.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            _picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            _picBox.BackColor = Color.Black;
            _picBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
            _displayedImage.Add(_picBox);

            return _picBox;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Message); return null;
        }
    }


private void MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            PictureBox pic = _testImage.AddPictureBox(e.X, e.Y);
            if(pic != null)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(pic);
                Trace.WriteLine("Picture box added");
            }
        }

        Trace.WriteLine("Mouse Click");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the new PictureBox to the form's controls collection.

You should return the newly created picturebox from your AddPictureBox and then add to the form's collection

```
public PictureBox AddPictureBox()
{
    try
    {
        PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
        ......
        return _picBox;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}


private void MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        PictureBox pic = _testImage.AddPictureBox();
        if(pic != null)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(pic);
            Trace.WriteLine("Picture box added");
    }
}
```

or, pass the instance of your form to the AddPictureBox method

```
public void AddPictureBox(Form f)
{
    try
    {
        PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
        ......
        f.Controls.Add(_picBox);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```